# History of the neusis construction of cube roots?

Tags: math-history, geometric-construction

A simple neusis (marked ruler) construction of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is given in many places, for example [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube).

My question is: what is the history of this construction?  As far as I can determine, all the ancient Greek constructions used either unmarked straight-edge, or a curve such as Nicomedes' conchoid or Diocles' cissoid.  Wikipedia references [Dörrie's *100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JZS8GIG), but Dörrie himself simply says that

> The simplest and most accurate method of obtaining $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is by
>   *paper-strip construction*.

In other words, using a neusis.  I don't know, however, if this construction originated with Dörrie or precedes him.

Does anybody know?

Comment: See [Neusis construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction) and the reference to T.L.Heath, [A history of Greek Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/History-Greek-Mathematics-Vol-Thales/dp/0486240738/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414930138&sr=8-1&keywords=Heath%2C+A+history+of+Greek+Mathematics) (1921 - Dover reprint, 2 vols), page 235-on : **The Trisection of any Angle**.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion!  However, I've had a brief look in Heath, but I can't find this construction.  There is a straight-line neusis construction by Nicomedes of the cube root of 2, but it is very different to Dörrie's.

Comment: I was wrong!  (what's new?) - I've been through Nicomede's construction (Heath Vol 1 p 261), and Dörrie's construction is just a simplified version of it.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486240738](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486240738)

Nicomedes managed to double the cube with neusis, and also described the conchoid of Nicomedes.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConchoidofNicomedes.html

" It is the locus of points a fixed distance away from a line as measured along a line from the focus point (MacTutor Archive)."

In 2002, Arthur Bartagar proved that neusis and conchoid-assisted constructions were mathematically equivalent.

https://baragar.faculty.unlv.edu/papers/TwiceNotch.pdf

He also proved that at least some irreducible rational quintics can be be solved with neusis/conchoids. (Note that the general equation to find the intersections of a circle with a conchoid of Nicomedes is a sextic polynomial equation)

It is known that neusis/conchoids can not solve irreducible rational septics, nor polynomials irreducible over the rationals whose degree has a prime factor of 7 or more. Whether all sextics and quintics can be solved by this method remains an open question.